# TCPDF MultiCell() places content as expected, draws border over previous cell

Tags: php, tcpdf

I have this block that creates a set of TCPDF `MultiCell()`s in a multicolumn pdf.

```
$TColW0 = 29;
$DColW0 = 37;
$mbh = $pdf->getStringHeight($DColW0, $reqHeader['partPackingInfo'], false, true, '', 1);
$pdf->MultiCell($TColW0, $mbh, 'Packaging Details:', 1, 'R', '', 0, '', '', true, 0, false, false, '', 'M', false);
$pdf->MultiCell($DColW0, $mbh, $reqHeader['partPackingInfo'], 1, 'L', '', 1, '', '', true, 0, false, false, '', 'M', false);
```

- The first line uses TCPDF's native function to get the height of the multi line string and sets the `$mbh` variable to later set both cells to the same height.
- The `$DColW0` and `$TColW0` variables are predetermined and set column widths.

My problem is the result looks like this,

[image: TCPDF Multiline Issue]

I tried using the title column's width in the `x` value of the data cell, but that just shifts the content out of the column.

The content looks to be in the right place the border for the data cell is just drawn in the wrong spot. Is there a setting or something I'm missing when it comes to `MultiCell()` borders? Any help/suggestions much appreciated.

---

Updating the block to make use of SetX

```
$TColW0 = 29;
$DColW0 = 37;
$mbh = $pdf->getStringHeight($DColW0, $reqHeader['partPackingInfo'], false, true, '', 1);
$pdf->MultiCell($TColW0, $mbh, 'Packaging Details:', 1, 'R', '', 0, '', '', true, 0, false, false, '', 'M', false);
$pdf->SetX($TColW0);
$pdf->MultiCell($DColW0, $mbh, $reqHeader['partPackingInfo'], 1, 'L', '', 1, '', '', true, 0, false, false, '', 'M', false);
```

Shifts the content independent of where the border is drawn.
[image: SETX Example]

---

Using the x specification inside of `MultiCell()`

```
$TColW0 = 29;
$DColW0 = 37;
$mbh = $pdf->getStringHeight($DColW0, $reqHeader['partPackingInfo'], false, true, '', 1);
$pdf->MultiCell($TColW0, $mbh, 'Packaging Details:', 1, 'R', '', 0, '', '', true, 0, false, false, '', 'M', false);
$pdf->MultiCell($DColW0, $mbh, $reqHeader['partPackingInfo'], 1, 'L', '', 1, $TColW0, '', true, 0, false, false, '', 'M', false);
```

[image]

Again content shifts, border is drawn over previous cell.

[MultiCell() Documentation.](https://tcpdf.org/docs/srcdoc/TCPDF/class-TCPDF/#_MultiCell)

---

Result with cell fill turned on.

```
$TColW0 = 29;
$DColW0 = 37;
$mbh = $pdf->getStringHeight($DColW0, $reqHeader['partPackingInfo'], false, true, '', 1);
$pdf->MultiCell($TColW0, $mbh, 'Packaging Details:', 1, 'R', 1, 0, '', '', true, 0, false, false, '', 'M', false);
$pdf->MultiCell($DColW0, $mbh, $reqHeader['partPackingInfo'], 1, 'L', 1, 1, '', '', true, 0, false, false, '', 'M', false);
```

[image: FillExample]

Turning fill on paints over all previously drawn borders for that row with the exception of the border for the last cell. The content of both cells is still in the expected position, the border is drawn to the expected size, but is drawn in the wrong position.

---

Parameters for Multicell;

```
MultiCell( $w, $h, $txt, $border = 0, $align = 'J', $fill = false, $ln = 1, $x = '', $y = '', $reseth = true, $stretch = 0, $ishtml = false, $autopadding = true, $maxh = 0, $valign = 'T', $fitcell = false )
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19817686/positioning-the-cell-in-pdf-using-fpdf/19817904#19817904

Comment: No good, content shifts but the border is still drawn over the previous cell.

Comment: The border is drawn right around the cell. If you have two borders overlapping, then you have two cells overlapping which means you don't understand the parameters for MultiCell. They are the same as Cell and they are explained in the post i linked earlier.

Comment: How can 2 cells be over lapping if the cell's content is not?

Comment: It's like creating a div of size 500 by 500, but only putting content the size of 200 by 200 in it. The content doesn't fill the entire div, but the border you draw on the div is still drawn on the 500 by 500 box.